# double-piping - undefined when options is not included?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I don't include the options in the `prepare()` parameter, I get an error: `Cannot read property 'min' of undefined`

How to solve this? without parameter included - it would set to null

```js
function prepare(options) {
  const data = {
  Minimum:options.min || null,
  Maximum: options.max || null
  }
  
  console.log(data)
}

prepare({
  min: 1
});

prepare();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **options && options.min** in case option can be undefined

> The error can be avoided using && to safe-guard against undefined.

try this:

```js
function prepare(options) {
 
  const data = {
  Minimum: options && options.min || null,
  Maximum: options && options.max || null
  }
  
  console.log(data)
}

prepare({
  min: 1
});

prepare();
```

Comment: What about `function prepare(options = {})` ?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back, yes it is solution also  to avoid undefined issue  :)